# Ionic Resizing Image from cordova-camera-preview?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, image-processing

So currently my image sizes from the phones camera are too big.

I'm using cordova-camera-preview-plugin, saving a file and using Ionic Native File to move this to a permanent location.

Now I'm trying to use ng2-img-tools to resize the image but it is complaining about the image not being a png/jpg which it is.

I think it's because the ng2-img-tools requires a File and I'm passing the location of the image.  So does anyone have any idea how to get around that?

Any help appreciated.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { Ng2ImgToolsService } from 'ng2-img-tools';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';

constructor(private file: File, public cameraPreview: CameraPreview, private ng2ImgToolsService: Ng2ImgToolsService) { }

    takePhoto()
      {

        this.cameraPreview.takePicture({quality: .7}).then((path) => {

          let tempPath = path[0].substr(0, path[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          let tempFileName = path[0].replace(tempPath, ""); 
          let fullTempPath = 'file://' + tempPath;

          var newFilename = this.createFileName();
          var permLocation = this.file.dataDirectory + newFilename;

          // Copy Image to Perm Directory....
          this.file.copyFile(fullTempPath, tempFileName, this.file.dataDirectory, newFilename).then(success => {

            var localLocation = window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(permLocation);

            this.ng2ImgToolsService.resize([localLocation], 640, 640).subscribe(result => {
                //all good, result is a file
                console.info(result);

            }, error => {
            });

          }, error => {

          });

        }, error => {

        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin ([CameraPreview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview)) has some options to play with:

```
// picture options
const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 1280,
  quality: 85,
  storeToFile: true
}

// take a picture
this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.pictureOpts).then((filePath) => {
  // here move filePath to the location you need, as it will be stored initially in a temp location.
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  this.picture = 'assets/img/test.jpg';
});
```

So I would recommend using options to reduce resolution at capture time as well as use feature to store the image as file (since base64 encoding adds a LOT of overhead)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, the width and height aren't for the actual outcome, just for the onscreen preview.  So I need to get those dimensions down.

Comment: @dunny ok but did you try to use file option vs base64? base64 adds significant overhead to your file size